# installed java 7 but terminal responds with version 6

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

So I installed Java 7 and verified that it was installed Java now shows up under System preferences. However when I run java -version it still returns

```
 java version "1.6.0_65
```

How do i fix this so that my computer points to the correct version? Also, is this a problem in the future if i choose to not fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you need to update your "PATH" environment variable with the path to the java bin directory of Java 7

Comment: probably **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** variable needs to modify.

Comment: to be on the safe side you should scan all your drives for java binaries, who knows which other versions are hidden there. If you don't remove old versions of Java you might unknowingly at some time open an unpatched version of Java which has known security problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your java 7 directory bin path to system `PATH` variable. As you are using Mac OS, use this article to set path correctly:

[JAVA HOME in Mac OS](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the following command to list the installed versions of Java:

   `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
2. From the output of the above command, copy the path for the version of Java you want to use.
3. Open up your **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.bashrc** file and add/edit the line:

   `export JAVA_HOME=/Path/copied/from/step/2`
4. In your terminal, reload the the file you edited in the previous step using the corresponding command below:

   `source ~/.bash_profile`

   `source ~/.bashrc`
5. Now, you should see the the correct version of Java on the command line:

   `java -version`